# Blank space at the bottom of page when using BACK with CHROME

Tags: php, html, css

Not sure how to ask this question properly.

If you go on the website I'm currently working on:

[My Website](http://bit.ly/O6vOSu)

The page loads fine, but if you go to another page or link afterwards and then hit BACK, the same page loads with a huge blank space at the bottom. If you refresh the page, it fixes itself. The website pcgamer.com seems to have the same problem.

Here is my HTML/PHP and CSS:

[Source Code](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_62QZdKCB4eLWhMcVVfT2hFUkE&usp=sharing)

EDIT 1: Removing the facebook plugin seems to solve the problem, but how can I use the plugin without having this issue ?

Comment: Sidenote: nice font, what is that font?  i think that your problem is the big image at background

Comment: Font: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lobster+Two The problem was the facebook plugin, not sure now how to add the plugin without getting that bug though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disable facebook like plugin and check it will fix your problem

Comment: Same problem here and removing FB Like button fixes it. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just check your web and I think I got your problem. You set .bodymainwrap to has height of 2100px. Please delete the css height:2100px; at .bodymainwrap selector. I'm sure it'll work.